# document.querySelector(); "Possibly the object is null" on making a FlipCard

Tags: javascript, html, css, next.js

Im trying to make a flipcard on Next.js with tsx but the querySelector('.cardflipper') dont find the object, given me this error: "Possibly the object is null". anybody knows how to make my method recognize my classnames or any other smart way to make a flipcard on tsx?

./components/FlipCard/index.tsx

```
import { Container } from './styles';
import React from 'react';



function FlipCard() {
  const cardflip = document.querySelector('.cardflipper');
  cardflip.addEventListener( 'click', function() {
  cardflip.classList.toggle('is-flipped');
});


  return (
    <Container>
      <div className="scene">
      <div className="cardflipper">
      <div className="card__face card__face--front">front</div>
      <div className="card__face card__face--back">back</div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </Container>
  );
}

export default FlipCard
```

./components/FlipCard/styled.ts

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

export const Container = styled.div`


.scene {
  width: 200px;
  height: 260px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  margin: 40px 0;
  perspective: 600px;
}

.cardflipper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: transform 1s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

.card.is-flipped {
  transform: translateX(-100%) rotateY(-180deg);
}

.card__face {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 260px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 40px;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.card__face--front {
  background: red;
}

.card__face--back {
  background: blue;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
`;
```

Comment: You should not do querySelector in react/next apps, instead learn useRef hook and how to use it, it will help you to access your DOM nodes inside your component. Besides that you are trying to add an EventListener which is not good, instead try adding inline handlers to your JSX elements.

Answer (score 0):

Simply typescript warning you that `querySelector` may return `null` if the `element` does not exist.

You can overcome this warning if you explicitly assign the returning type with `as HTMLDivElement`.

```
  const cardflip = document.querySelector('.cardflipper') as HTMLDivElement;
```

Better alternative, you can use `template ref`

```
import { Container } from './styles';
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';



function FlipCard() {
  const flippingCardRef = useRef()
  useEffect(() => {
    flippingCardRef.current.addEventListener('click', function() {
      flippingCardRef.current.classList.toggle('is-flipped');
    });
  });


  return (
    <Container>
      <div className="scene">
      <div className="cardflipper" ref={flippingCardRef}>
      <div className="card__face card__face--front">front</div>
      <div className="card__face card__face--back">back</div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </Container>
  );
}

export default FlipCard
```

Comment: Thanks mate, now it is throwing me this error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')"

Comment: You are welcome, You need to execute `click` event listener after the component is mounted, in `useEffect` hook, I just update the answer please check again.